# How to get an html based representation of a pdf file

Tags: java, pdf, structure, extract, converters

I searched a lot and haven't found a tool that fits my needs.

I get pdf files and want to display its content on a webpage.

The representation of the pdf content should be html, as i also want to highlight specific words and want to be able to include the pdf's content without having some sort of flash or javascript plugin that handles the rendering.

At best would be a java library. Commercial or free to use is not important. Open is better, free would be nice.

The available pdf tools like **jPedal, PDFBox, iText, and others** didn't work good enough

JPedal did the job quite good, except for issues with fonts on a linux system. The library tries to render the html page exacly like the original page. But this is not important for me. I need paragraph grouped togeher and headlines that have the size of the originals. It does not matter is a paragraph has more height.

PdfBox does either only redurn a single String containing the while content, or makes list of html <p> tags for each line on the page.

I also know that reading the contents of a pdf is a hard task, but is there really nothing one can use??

Please tell me that there is already a solution.

Update:

I also need to get the html representation of the document to further manipulate it on the server.

It is not very important, that each page looks like the original pages. The height of the paragraphs can vary, also headers and footers are not important. But it would be nice.

I'll test PDFNet in a few days, thanks for the hint

Comment: There is a reason that thousands of web sites put links to their PDF files, rather than try to convert PDF files to HTML.

Comment: I helped to write the PDF converter based around JPedal and it has 5 different display modes including real text, test as shapes and invisible text on image for selection. If you have an issue with any file you are welcome to send us a bug report. If you just want a free tool to show PDF files dynamically, have a look a PDF.js